# Counting algorithm for 2D arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, count

If I have a 2D array (2 columns, 10000 rows, example below) where in the first column are some numerical values and the 2nd column an indicator (either 1 or 0). What is the most efficient algorithm ever (in terms of computing speed) to count the number of 1's between 2 numerical values for example between 200 and 800?
A 2D array example:

```
#2A((315 1)
    (1941 1)
    (1914 0)
    (970 1)
    (1600 0)
    (283 0)
    (843 0)
    (1831 1)
    (1584 1)
    (1918 1)
        ...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Approach 1

If you only want to perform the operation once then you cannot do better than O(n) because you need to examine each entry at least once:

```
for each item
  if low<=item[0]<=high and item[1]==1:
     count += 1
```

### Approach 2

If you want to do multiple queries then one approach would be to discard all the items with 0's, sort the remaining items, then for each query use bisection to find the number of items in the given range.

This would be O(nlogn) for the sorting (this only needs to be done once) plus O(logn) for each query.

### Approach 3

If your numbers are in a fixed range of length B, then you could set an array with the count of how many items (with value 1) are at each bin, then compute the cumulative sum of this array.

This would give an O(n+B) preprocessing time, plus O(1) for each query

Comment: I used approach 2. Thanks. Unfortunately I did not understand approach #3.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is not sorted, there is nothing much you can do but going to each pair (a,b) of the array checking if a is in the bound and b = 1. This is obviously a O(n) algorithm.